# Prove (members of a recursive set) by structural induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Trying to prove, using structural induction only, that every member of the following recursively defined set  has a remainder of 1 when divided by 4

$1 ∈ $

$ ∈  → 5 ∈ $

$ ∈  → ^2 ∈ $

So...

*The number one is in the set S.*

*n in the set S implies 5n is in the set S.*

*n in the set S implies $n^2$ is also in the set S.*

I think I am confusing something here in the way that I am reading this set information; any starting hint would be great. I am used to recursion in programming but my idea of it may be incorrect when applying it to Discrete mathematics.

I need to go to sleep but will update this in the morning after I attempt the problem. I am unsure how to setup a proof for this. Hopefully I figure it out before I even log back onto my computer!

Thank you all in advance, I've learned so much from using this website in the past week.

Comment: In the third and fourth line, do you mean $n \in S \implies n^2 \in S$?

Comment: My apologies!! I will update that now. Thank you for noticing this, I am half asleep of course I would mess that up :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean $n \in S \implies n^2 \in S$. If not, I'll edit the answer.

Note that $1 \in S \implies 5 \in S \implies 25 \in S \cdots$.

You can prove using induction that for any non-negative integer $i,\,\, 5^i \in S$. You can also prove that these are the only elements of this set (using contradiction).

Now, again use the fact that $$1 \equiv 1 \mod 4$$ and $$5 \equiv 1 \mod 4$$ to prove that $$\forall i, \quad 5^i \equiv 1 \mod 4\qquad i \ge 1,\quad i \in \mathbb Z$$

**Alternatively,** *(More structural inductive approach)*

Base Case: $1\equiv 1 \mod 4$

Induction hypothesis: Let all elements after at most $k$ operations, have remainder $1 \mod 4$.

Induction step: Now, in one more step (i.e. total $k+1$ steps), we produce elements with remainder $1 \mod 4$. Let $s_i$ be an element in step after at most $k$ steps. Now, by induction hypothesis, $s_i = 4k+1$ for some $k$.

**Rule 1:** $n \in S \implies 5n \in S$.

$5(s_i) = 5(4k+1) = 20k+5 = 20k+4+1 \equiv 1 \mod 4$

**Rule 2:** $n \in S \implies n^2 \in S$.

$(s_i)^2 = (4k+1)^2 = 16k^2 + 8k+1 \equiv 1 \mod 4$.

Thus, all elements of $S$ leave remainder of $1 \mod 4$

Comment: Ah I am so bad with Modulus, I understand it is the remainder and that is simple.. There is just something about reading it this way versus in a computer program that gets my mind racing and confused. I will look at this in the morning, thank you for giving me the starting hints!!

Comment: @mar10 Added another simpler method which is more inductive than before.

Comment: Wow.. Thank you so much! You made my day so much easier. I wish I could give you dozens of up 'up votes'.

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ defined here as the 'smallest' set such that the mentioned conditions are satisfied then it is enough to prove that the set $A:=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid n\equiv 1\mod 4\}$ satisfies the conditions:

- $1\equiv 1\mod 4$
- If $n\equiv 1\mod 4$ then $5n\equiv 1\mod 4$
- If $n\equiv 1\mod 4$ then $n^2\equiv 1\mod 4$

It is evident that this is true and our conclusion is $S\subseteq A$